# trick question regarding declaration syntax in C++

Tags: c++, syntax

Have a look here:
In the following code, what would be the type of b?

```
struct A {
    A (int i) {}
};

struct B {
    B (A a) {}
};

int main () {
    int i = 1;
    B b(A(i)); // what would be the type of b
    return 0;
}
```

I'll appreciate it if anybody could explain to me thoroughly why would such syntax exist :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of C's warts (and C++ inherits it (and makes it worse)) is that there is no special syntax for introducing a declaration.  This means declarations often look like executable code.  Another example:

```
A * a;
```

Is this multiplying A by a, or is it declaring something?  In order to make sense of this line you have to know that A is the name of a type.

The basic rule in C++ is that if something can be parsed as a declaration, it is.  In this instance it leads to a strange and surprising result.  Function declarations look a lot like function calls, and in particular the ( after the A can be thought of in a couple of ways.

You can get around this in this example with extra parenthesis that remove the compiler's ability to parse the code as a declaration.

```
B b((A(i)));
```

In C this isn't ambiguous because there is no function style of constructor call because there are no constructors.  A is either the name of a type, or it's the name of a function.  It can't be both.

Comment: I believe you could also do: B b = B(A(i));

Comment: Yes, that would also work, is easier to understand and less ugly.  :-)

Comment: ... but means a different thing - `B b = B(...)` requires `B` to have a copy constructor (even though the compiler can optimize the call to it away, it is still required to check), while `B b(...)` does not require it.

Answer (score 7):

It is a local function declaration according to C++ Standard 8.2/1. You could use implicit form of constructor to avoid this or the following:

```
B b(A(i)); // is equal to B b( A i );

// ---

// to declare variable of type B write:
B b = A(i);
// explicit form if you want:
B b( static_cast<A>(A(i)) );
// or
B b( (A)i );
```

C++ Standard 8.2/1:

> The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a function-style cast and a declaration mentioned in 6.8
>   can also occur in the context of a declaration.  In that context, the choice is between a function declaration
>   with a redundant set of parentheses around a parameter name and an object declaration with a function-style
>   cast as the initializer.  Just as for the ambiguities mentioned in 6.8, the resolution is to consider any con-
>   struct that could possibly be a declaration a declaration.

Answer (score 5):

```
B b(A(i));
```

is equivalent to

```
B b(A i);
```

- the parenthesis around the argument name are optional -, which is equivalent to

```
B b(A);
```

- the parameter name is optional in function declarations. Hence it is a function declaration.

Typically you run into it with

```
X x();
```

- not default constructor as expected -, but there are more complicated cases when using temporaries all the way, e.g

```
vector<int> v(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>());
```

Comment: Unexpectedly, it turned into a good argument against `using namespace` :)

Comment: Unfortunately it goes deeper than that. If cin had been std::cin then GCC determines that this line indeed constructs a vector object, whereas VC++ (2005) complains that std::cin cannot appear as parameter name.

Comment: @UncleBens, Unfortunately, GCC is wrong with that and VC++ is correct. See my defect report to clang: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=4594