# C++0x move constructor gotcha

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor

*Edit:* I re-asked this same question (after fixing the problems noted with this question) here: [Why does this C++0x program generates unexpected output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186446/why-does-this-c0x-program-generates-unexpected-output)

The basic idea is that pointing to moveable things may net you some odd results if you aren't careful.

---

The C++ move constructor and move assignment operator seem like really positive things.  And they can be used in situations where the copy constructor makes no sense because they don't require duplicating resources being pointed at.

But there are cases where they will bite you if you aren't careful.  And this is especially relevant as I've seen proposals to allow the compiler to generate default implementations of the move constructor.  I will provide a link to such if someone can give me one.

So, here is some code that has some flaws that may not be completely obvious.  I tested the code to make sure it compiles in g++ with the `-std=gnuc++0x` flag.  What are those flaws and how would you fix them?

```
#if (__cplusplus <= 199711L) && !defined(__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__)
   #error This requires c++0x
#endif

#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>

class ObserverInterface {
 public:
   virtual ~ObserverInterface() {}

   virtual void observedChanged() = 0;
   virtual void observedGoingAway() = 0;
};

class Observed {
 private:
   typedef ::std::unordered_set<ObserverInterface *> obcontainer_t;

 public:
   Observed() {}
   Observed(const Observed &) = delete;
   const Observed &operator =(const Observed &b) = delete;
   // g++ does not currently support defaulting the move constructor.
   Observed(Observed &&b) : observers_(::std::move(b.observers_)) { }
   // g++ does not currently support defaulting move assignment.
   const Observed &operator =(Observed &&b) {
      observers_ = ::std::move(b.observers_);
      return *this;
   }
   virtual ~Observed() {
      for (auto i(observers_.begin()); i != observers_.end(); ++i) {
         (*i)->observedGoingAway();
      }
   }

   void unObserve(ObserverInterface *v) {
      auto loc(observers_.find(v));
      if (loc != observers_.end()) {
         observers_.erase(loc);
      }
   }

   void changed() {
      if (!observers_.empty()) {
         // Copy observers_ to bector so unObserve works
         ::std::vector<ObserverInterface *> tmp;
         tmp.reserve(observers_.size());
         tmp.assign(observers_.begin(), observers_.end());

         for (auto i(tmp.begin()); i != tmp.end(); ++i) {
            (*i)->observedChanged();
         }
      }
   }

 private:
   obcontainer_t observers_;
};

class Observer : public ObserverInterface {
 public:
   Observer() {}
   Observer(const Observer &) = delete;
   const Observer &operator =(const Observer &b) = delete;
   // g++ does not currently support defaulting the move constructor.
   Observer(Observer &&b) : observed_(b.observed_) {
      b.observed_ = 0;
      return *this;
   }
   // g++ does not currently support defaulting move assignment.
   const Observer &operator =(Observer &&b) {
      observed_ = b.observed_;
      b.observed_ = 0;
      return *this;
   }
   virtual ~Observer() {
      if (observed_) {
         observed_->unObserve(this);
         observed_ = 0;
      }
   }

   virtual void observedChanged() {
      doStuffWith(observed_);
   }
   virtual void observedGoingAway() {
      observed_ = 0;
   }

 private:
   Observed *observed_;

   // Defined elsewhere
   void doStuffWith(Observed *);
};
```

Comment: Is this a quiz? Do you know what the flaws are?

Comment: there is no "correct" answer as this requires discussion. Better Community Wiki it if you want this to even have a chance at not getting closed....

Comment: @Greg Hewgill, I know what the flaws are.  I notice that there are several people who ask questions they know the answers to because they think the answers to the questions will be useful and instructive to have on the site.  This is such a question.

Comment: @earlz, there is a correct answer.

Comment: For a reference to another question like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379932/trick-question-regarding-declaration-syntax-in-c

Comment: @Omni, that question asks for the reasoning and rationale behind the syntax. Your question reminds me of a short lecture and quiz I'd get in my programming class.

Comment: @earlz, how would you suggest I ask the question then?  Do you think that having a question about potential problems with move constructors is bad?

Comment: I've only figured one flaw in my quick scan: Forgotten to `return *this;` in assignment operator. But not sure whether that has directly to do with move semantics. :(

Comment: @earlz, should I disingenuously add some code that exercises these classes and then asks why I get segmentation faults seemingly randomly?

Comment: @Johannes, oops!  *sheepish grin*  Fixed!

Comment: @Omnifarious: For such an "I know the answers, do you?" kind of question to be useful, it has to be specific enough that people who can learn from it will actually *find* it. It's currently too open-ended for that. If you want to provide answers to questions that others haven't asked yet, then make the question so specific that people who *want* to ask it will find it.

Comment: @jalf, that makes sense.  I voted to close this question, and I will revise it and ask it in a different way.

Comment: If you're still interested: give [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) a try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of problems with the code.

1. `Observer::observed_` is left uninitialized in the default constructor, leading to an undefined behavior when the destructor gets called.
2. No value but 0 is ever assigned to `Observer::observed_`, making the variable superfluous.
3. Even if there was a way to associate an observer with an observed, you're not re-registering when moving the observer.
4. You're trying to return a value from observer's move constructor.
5. [Boost.Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/signals.html) already solves whatever problem you're trying to solve.
6. It is more idiomatic to return non-const reference from assignment operators.

Comment: *sigh*  Thanks.  You've highlighted enough problems that aren't related to what I was thinking of that I think I should delete the question and start over.

Comment: Though, you got one of the problems I was thinking of.  #3.